# build/ihp-lib/Makefile.dist: No such file or directory

Tags: ihp

```
$ make -B build/ihp-lib
Makefile:30: build/ihp-lib/Makefile.dist: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'build/ihp-lib/Makefile.dist'.  Stop.
```

> Try to run make -B build/ihp-lib to create the symlink.
> https://github.com/digitallyinduced/ihp/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

```
$ nix-shell --run 'make build/ihp-lib'
Makefile:30: build/ihp-lib/Makefile.dist: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'build/ihp-lib/Makefile.dist'.  Stop.
```

`which RunDevServer` does not return `RunDevServer not found`.

`curl --silent https://raw.githubusercontent.com/digitallyinduced/ihp/master/Troubleshoot/ihp-troubleshoot | python3` shows only the following error.

```
+ Symlink build/ihp-lib exists
- Symlink build/ihp-lib target directory does not exist. Try `nix-shell --run "make -B build/ihp-lib"` to fix this
```

Comment: Can you run the autotroubleshooting script via `curl --silent https://raw.githubusercontent.com/digitallyinduced/ihp/master/Troubleshoot/ihp-troubleshoot | python3` ? This might be lead to helpful details

Answer (score 1):

[This is a common issue listed on the Troubleshooting documentation.](https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/troubleshooting.html)

Try this:

```
rm build/ihp-lib
nix-shell --run 'make build/ihp-lib'
```